# Ubuntu 23.04 terminal loading

Tags: command-line

When opening ubuntu 23.04 terminal is too slow loading. also my pc first installed 22.04 and then upgrade to 22.10 lastly upgraded 23.04.

Comment: Settings from the previous versions might cause the slowdown. You should consider a fresh installation (but first you should backup everything that you cannot afford to lose (documents, pictures ...)

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Try to open a terminal from another terminal, just to be clear, open a terminal, even it is slow, let it open, then run the program name like gnome-terminal or konsole, depends upon your terminal name. Did you see any error ?